# Move/Transfer Files using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Is there a way to transfer files utilizing postgresql? Meaning as a part of my loop import I want to transfer the file from Directory1 to Directory2 after it has been imported. My loop import is below. I would like to transfer the file after the update that gives me the filename. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  directory_path VARCHAR(500);
  rec RECORD;
BEGIN
   directory_path := 'C:\Directory1\';
    FOR rec IN SELECT pg_ls_dir(directory_path) AS file_name
    LOOP
      EXECUTE format(
            'COPY public.mytable("column1","column2","column3")
FROM %L DELIMITER ''|'' CSV HEADER;', directory_path || rec.file_name);
UPDATE public.mytable
SET filename = rec.file_name
WHERE filename is null;
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PL/PerlU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/PythonU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) languages to do that inside the database.

Using these "untrusted" languages, you can do practically everything.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however no matter how I install Python the command "CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu" results with "could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory". A google search shows that many people have had this problem, but I have yet to find out how to resolve it.